# AJAX : Passing null parameter in GET request

Tags: ajax, url, parameters, null, camunda

I couldn't find anything, so I'm asking here for a little help! I'm sure it's super easy but I'm stucked anyway.

I've created an MVC application in order to gather data (in AJAX) from Camunda via their REST api. One property of the stuff (tasks, to be more precise) that I need to get is "assignee". This value is usually filled with a username, but it can be empty (in that case, it's filled with "null").

But here's the problem: I can't manage to gather tasks with this value (In fact, i'd like to display each task of a given user, including tasks that are not assigned to anyone, so they can claim them to themselves if they want to). The url I use in AJAX is like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/task?assignee=peter
```

I've tried these parameters with no success (no task displayed at all ; even Peter's, obvisouly):

```
task?assignee=peter%2Cundefined
task?assignee=peter%00
task?assignee=peter%2Cnull
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so any "Hello" stuff is removed...

Comment: If a parameter is not there it is generally considered null. Is there a case where that will not work for you? (ie `http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/task` if assignee is null)

Comment: Doing this will result in showing all the tasks, whereas assignee is null or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that exactly this is doable via Camunda REST API. If I am not mistaken, there is no way for specifying a condition `assignee = peter OR assignee is null`.

I can think of two options:

### 1. Make two queries

One with `task?assignee=peter`, another with `task?unassigned=true` and join the lists (they should be disjunctive). See http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#task-get-tasks for a description of the parameters.

### 2. Make a native query using the Java API

Native queries allow you to express arbitrary conditions, however can be only performed using the Java API. See http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-process-engine-api-native-queries for details on native queries.

In this example, the code would be

```
List<Task> tasks = taskService.createNativeTaskQuery()
  .sql("SELECT count(*) FROM " + managementService.getTableName(Task.class) + " T WHERE T.ASSIGNEE_ = #{assignee} OR T.ASSIGNEE_ IS NULL")
  .parameter("assignee", "peter")
  .list();
```

If you want to expose this in the REST API, embedding and extending its resources in a custom JAX-RS application could be a way to go, see http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#overview-embedding-the-api

Comment: Ok I tried your first solution and it work well thanks. I feel really stupid as it was mentionned in the doc (which I used a lot though!).

Anyway I think I'm gonna try to code this in C# instead, as I'm getting the famous CORS error when I try to POST in AJAX... So I will use your second point I guess.